# Exact DE not matching.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have DE that is exact and I need to find the answer. Here's the problem:

$$(-(2x^2+4y))dx + (4y^2-4x)dy= 0$$

I have checked and they are both exact.

I integrated the M in respect to x, then I differentiated in respect to y to find h'(y).

My answer came out to be

$$F(x,y) = \frac{4y^3}{3}-4xy$$

However,this is not correct. I have asked someone to solve it as well and he got the same answer.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to add the $x$'s terms. It should be:$$F(x,y) = -2/3x^3 - 4xy + 4/3y^3.$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\left( -\left( 2x^{ 2 }+4y \right)  \right) dx+\left( 4y^{ 2 }-4x \right) dy=0\\ \left( -2{ x }^{ 2 }dx+4{ y }^{ 2 }dy \right) -4\left( ydx+xdy \right) =0\\ d\left( -\frac { 2 }{ 3 } x^{ 3 }+\frac { 4 }{ 3 } { y }^{ 3 } \right) -4d\left( xy \right) =0\\ d\left( -\frac { 2 }{ 3 } x^{ 3 }+\frac { 4 }{ 3 } { y }^{ 3 }-4xy \right) =0\\ -\frac { 2 }{ 3 } x^{ 3 }+\frac { 4 }{ 3 } { y }^{ 3 }-4xy=C\\ $$